# Warning displayed even though the file is detected in QgsMessageBar

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I try to display a warning message when a file is not found in a folder but I don't understand why the warning message appears even if the layer is loaded.

I used `if` then `else` but it is not working.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
import os

folder = "C:/Users/Desktop/working_folder"

os.chdir(folder)
wholelist = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

for file in wholelist:
    if "shapefile1.shp" in file:
            filefolder= folder +'\\'+file
            shapefile1 = QgsVectorLayer(filefolder,file[:-4],"ogr")
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(shapefile1)
            print(filefolder)
    else:
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "shapefile1 has not been found in :" + folder, level=Qgis.Warning)
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your script always shows a message bar. Because you iterate on `wholelist`. Instead, you should iterate on file names to be checked.

First, define a list containing the file names to be checked and to be added to the project. Then check if each is in `wholelist`.

```
files_to_be_checked = ["shapefile1.shp", "shapefile2.shp"] # and so on

for file in files_to_be_checked:
    if file in wholelist:
        fileroute = folder + '\\' + file
        shapefile1 = QgsVectorLayer(fileroute, file[:-4], "ogr")
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(shapefile1)
        print(fileroute)
    else:
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", file + " has not been found in " + folder, level=Qgis.Warning)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but if I do this way it loads all the layers (shapefile2, shapefile3 and so on) to my project

Answer (score 5):

You need to move the message out of the loop (or it will fire for all the missing files)

```
found = False
for file in wholelist:
    if "shapefile1.shp" in file:
        filefolder= folder +'\\'+file
        shapefile1 = QgsVectorLayer(filefolder,file[:-4], "ogr")
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(shapefile1)
        print(filefolder)
        found = True
if !found:
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "shapefile1 has not been found in :" + folder, level=Qgis.Warning)
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, I understand better how it works thanks to your answer !